# How to remove complete session of particular user, after he loggedout in java?

Tags: java, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After logout also user is performing operations ,what code i have to write to prevent that loggedout user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620809/after-logout-also-user-is-performing-operations-what-code-i-have-to-write-to-pr)

How to remove complete session of a particular user, after he logged out, in java?.I mean the user can not perform any operation on that website without again logging in.And whenever user clicks on 'logout' he should be taken to welcome page and backbutton should not work. Can anybody help.....?

Comment: You posted them same query in different ways all over again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620809/after-logout-also-user-is-performing-operations-what-code-i-have-to-write-to-pr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580863/how-to-remove-complete-session-of-particular-user-after-he-loggedout-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618934/how-to-prevent-access-to-loggedout-user-to-a-perticular-link-all-links-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644145/without-refreshing-the-website-a-loggedout-user-can-login-again-in-gwti-am-gett