# After logout also user is performing operations ,what code i have to write to prevent that loggedout user?

Tags: java, gwt

All! After logout also user is performing operations in my created website which was developed in gwt and java ,what  code i have to write to prevent that user?. I mean how to write code to prevent the user operations after 'logout'. whenever the user is going to click on any link on the page after logout,just he should see the message "You are not logged in to view",this is my requirement .can anybody say?....thanks bala...

Comment: Please provide code snippets relevant to your efforts. You need to handle the log out by invalidating the user's  http session in a filter or url-pattern based servlet redirection.

Comment: You posted them same query in different ways all over again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620809/after-logout-also-user-is-performing-operations-what-code-i-have-to-write-to-pr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580863/how-to-remove-complete-session-of-particular-user-after-he-loggedout-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618934/how-to-prevent-access-to-loggedout-user-to-a-perticular-link-all-links-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644145/without-refreshing-the-website-a-loggedout-user-can-login-again-in-gwti-am-gett

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Activities and Places approach to structure your website.
Then on start of each activity you should check if the session is still valid.
If not then you can use either goTo(new LoginPlace("login")) or you can use redirect approach to redirect to your loginURL.

Comment: By using  goTo(new LoginPlace("login")) we can call this place on the browser,but we can't prevent the user access after longout.....can you send me proper one which will not allow the user to do any operation after logout....thanks

Comment: When u invalidate session and on start of any activity you redirect to other place.How user can access an intermedite URL then ?

Comment: In my website homepage/welcome page i have somany links,let us suppose take it as "MyProfile",after  the user logout from the webpage if he is going to click on "myprofile" then it's automatically opens.It is visible,let us suppose,then how to make the user not to access the "myprofile" link even it is visible.?Can you say?.....thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: On Click of "My Profile" link there will be new acivity starting.
On Start of that activity you can check if session is active.If it does you can allow user to access else you can "redirect user to other page for example login".I guess you should read how [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#Activities) Activities and Places work

Comment: If we click on any link on the welcome page except longin and register ,the message should be display like "YOu are not logged in to view this page",Can you send me code  in GWT?....THANKS....

Comment: Redirection is only part of the solution. You need to invalidate the HttpSession for the user!!! Otherwise as soon as the user clicks on the login url it will pick up the old session and continue. Usually we go with simple jsp page for login and logout page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect him to your logout page/url and then invalidate his servlet session.

1) Servlet Filter and in that you can invalidate the session with `httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate()`. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-session-handling-tutorial-using-servlet-filters-session-error-filter-servlet-filter/

or

2) Via a simple servlet - [Servlet session invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004417/servlet-session-invalidate)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/loginmanager) link
This explains how do you write login app using GWT

Or as in Code..If you have MyProfilePlace,MyProfileView then MyProfileActivity will look like

```
private ClientFactory clientFactory;

      public MyProfileActivity(MyProfilePlace place, ClientFactory clientFactory) {

    this.clientFactory = clientFactory;

 }

@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget containerWidget, EventBus eventBus) {

            //pseudo code
    if (session invalidated {
        Window.alert("Sorry you are not logged in");
        goTo(new LoginPlace("login"));
    }

    view = clientFactory.getMyProfileView();
    view.setPresenter(this);
    containerWidget.setWidget(view.asWidget());
    System.out.println("Going to your profile");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir,i will try with this,,i will intimate you after completion of this functionality working....thanks,,,bala

Comment: sir! I have more links like "MyProfile" ,i think it's burden to the programmer to write in each and every activity,view and impl class.Can you say common for all links that if we click on any link it should disply "You are not loggedin to view this page" except register and login?,right?...thanks ..bala

Comment: Sir ! Did you catch my above question?

Answer (score 0):

Consider what session actually is...
Now, remember what is the common (NOT the only) way of maintaining the session.

Maybe you will remember such thing as cookies - if you (attempt to) delete/remove/clear the session on the server **AND** clear cookies on the client's side you will effectively kill/remove the session.

Comment: I want to write it in my source code,then how to write,to clear the entire session of a perticular user after he loggedout from the website.I am using MYSQL database...can you say sir..?

Comment: In your server side source code logout handling you will have to  delete/remove/clear session, look up (depends on application server) how and do that.  
Than you will have to clear cookies in your client's browser using JavaScript - Google how to do that.

Comment: can you send me code for that in java if possible,so that i will proceed ,thanks & regards,bala nagaraju.

Comment: I tried as you said but ,it's not working. Can you give example code to this?....thanks & regards...bala.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this scenario when a user does a click on a button on the screen. 
You can make a server hit and check whether session is alive or not.

(You can do this by using jquery)

> ```
> $('button').click(function(){
> ```
>
> //make ajax call and check is session is alive
>
> ```
> });
> ```

Alternate to this,

Method can be to check the server regularly, if a session is valid. 
Servlet method will be needed for this which checks this,this will result in many of server trips.

Another method can be keeping a timer on client side synchronous with the server's timer.

Code on client :

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
```

public class Timers {

```
private static final Timer SESSION_MAY_HAVE_EXPIRED = new Timer() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // The session may have expired.
        // Go to Login
    }
};

public static void renewSessionTimer() {

    // First cancel the previous timer
    SESSION_MAY_HAVE_EXPIRED.cancel();

    // Schedule again for 5 minutes
    SESSION_MAY_HAVE_EXPIRED.schedule(5 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

}

Server sessions timeout will be renewed when client performs a RPC call.

On Client side then you write code on failure of any action.

Suppose on click of my profile.myprofileService get called.
Then you can add

```
myProfileService.getUserProfile(...) {

 @Override
 public void onSuccess(String result) {

      ClientTimers.renewSessionTimer();

      // Show user profile
 }

 @Override
 public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

      if (sessionTimedOut()) {

          // redirect to login

      }   

}
```

}

I hope this helps.
Cheers :)

Comment: Sir! Right now my problem is solved by using clear() method.Now my problem is,let us take one user .He has logged into the web site by using his username and password ,after he has logged out.Then once again he wants to logg in the website by using his old credentials without refreshing the page,exactly at this situation the browser shows NullPointerException.What's the code for once again login into the website without refreshing the website after first time he loggedout from webpage in GWT? thanks .....bala